# Java equivalent to .NET SSLStream

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to write a custom proxy server to handle https connection. Is there anything in Java that's equivalent to .NET SSLStream ?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use `SSLSocketFactory` for creating a SSL `ServerSocket`. The related server socket will take care about(has specific/implemented `in` and `out` streams) data encryption and related processes.
You may specify the SSL settings as system properties as following.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "<<path of your key>>");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "<<store passwd if specified>>");
//System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

Later, you need to initialize the `ServerSocket` as following

```
int port=3128,backlog=32;
ServerSocket ss=SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port, backlog, InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress());
```

The rest work is just like plain(non-ssl) process, just listen for a request and proceed it.

```
while(ss.isBound()){
Socket s=ss.accept();
InputStram in=s.getInputStream();
OutputStream os=s.getOutputStream();
//.....rest of teh work
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you must listen to unencrypted CONNECT requests to be able to know the host and ip, then encrypt the channel.